# Sencha+ cordova + WP8 : SQL proxy issue, openDatabase is undefined

Tags: sql, windows-phone-8, sencha-touch-2, cordova-3, opendatabase

I am trying to integrate a sencha app on windows phone 8 using cordova.

This Sencha app uses a store with SQL proxy. 
On running this app on device, I get an error: "openDatabase is undefined".

If I remove the SQL proxy, I see no errors and the app launches fine.

What could be the reason for SQL proxy failing on windows phone?

This app has been packaged for iOS and Android and it works fine.